# Cantor's diagonal argument applied to real numbers in a countable model

Tags: set-theory

I am trying to understand how the following things fit together. Please note that I am a beginner in set theory, so anywhere I made a technical mistake, please assume the "nearest reasonable statement" to what I wrote. The set theory assumed here is ZF or ZFC. (I am not sure what difference would either choice make.)

First assumption: We have the set of natural numbers, which can be created in every model of set theory, using Axiom of Infinity. Then we can e.g. create integers as pairs of natural numbers, rational numbers as pairs of integers, and real numbers as Dedekind cuts.

Second, Skolem's paradox says that there is a countable model of set theory, where, if I understand it correctly, the previous construction would only create a countable amount of "real numbers". That is, countable from the *outside* perspective; however, in-universe, the set seems uncountable, because the bijections between the naturals (of the model) and "reals" (of the model), although possible from the outside perspective, are not recognized *by the model* as sets.

(Sidenote: The whole approach of "one set is greater than the other if there is only an injection from one side" now seems a bit confused to me, because it doesn't seem to distinguish between sets where a bijection is impossible *in principle*, for example finite sets of different sizes, and sets where the bijection is merely *not known to the model*. In other words, the "greater" relation may be a fact about the *sets*, or it may be a fact about the *model*, and we treat both as if it is the same thing. I suppose someone already made this objection decades ago; does it have a standard name?)

Now my question is, suppose there is a mathematician living inside the countable universe, investigating the "real" numbers (in the countable model). His work is observed by a mathematician from outside, from whose perspective the former universe is countable, and therefore its "reals" are countable, and therefore *not isomorphic* to the actual (from the second mathematician's perspective) reals.

So the first mathematician goes, step by step, from defining the natural numbers, through defining the reals, until the Cantor's diagonal argument about how the infinity of reals is greater than the infinity of integers... and his work is at each step verified by the second mathematician. At which step exactly would the second mathematician exclaim "wrong!", if ever?

If the answer to the previous question is "never", does it imply that there could be a universe outside our own, from whose perspective *our* real numbers are actually quite countable, it's just that our set theory says "for *technical reasons*, this obvious bijection is dismissed, because it is not considered to be a set"? (Furthermore, does it imply that *all* infinite sets are in some sense countable, you just need to be in a sufficiently larger model to clearly see the bijection between the natural numbers and the given set?)

That is, does Cantor's diagonal argument only prove that in each model, there are bijections that the model is *unable to see*, or that some sets are... you know... *essentially* greater than other sets? (But if it's the latter, why can the mathematician in the countable universe prove the same fact about the natural numbers and the countable "reals"?)

Comment: This is not an answer, but I think you're tripping yourself up some from a set theory perspective in assuming that there is a 'global' perspective and a 'true' theory of these things. If the model can't see it, then for all intents and purposes it _doesn't_ exist. In your two-mathematicians model, the second mathematician has a bijection between the first mathematician's reals and the 'exterior' $\mathbb{N}$, but there is no way for the first mathematician to 'know' that; that object simply doesn't exist to them.

Comment: @Steven - I am curious where *a larger model* can exist where something is true. For example, if I have a set with 3 elements and a set of 4 elements, I believe there is *no* larger model that would contain a bijection between them. But if I have N and R, is it possible for a larger model to exist with a bijection between "my N" and "my R" , or does Cantor's diagonal argument make it impossible *in principle*? (If it's the latter, than what would happen if a person inside a countable universe tried the same for "their N" and "their R"?)

Comment: That's a very complicated question to answer — the notion of building models from other models is the core idea behind the concept of _forcing_, and much of modern set theory since then.

Comment: @ViliamBúr It is actually possible that two sets within a model are finite and of different size from point of this model, but from outside we see that they have the same size and are in fact infinite (!)

Comment: @Jonathan Those have to be some pretty dubious models; isn't finiteness absolute?

Comment: @ViliamBúr These are models which are not $\omega$-models, i.e. models that have non-standard natural numbers.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki. Finiteness is  absolute for transitive standard models. Finiteness is not absolute for all models.  If $E$ is  binary relation on $M$, and the model is $\Bbb M =(M,E)$ where $(x\in y)^{\Bbb M}\iff xEy,$ then finiteness can fail to be absolute. In ZFC even if you assume there is  set-model for [ZFC] you still can't prove there is a  standard model.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet (and Jonathan) Fair on both counts; thank you! I would definitely say that $\omega$-inconsistency falls into the 'dubious' camp, though nonstandard models are certainly nifty.

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you! Could you perhaps recommend me a good textbook on this topic (models with non-standard naturals)? I see the rabbit hole goes way deeper than I assumed.